# Images Not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, background-image

I have a MVC Project

Click this url :

> http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/

Then Click this url :

> http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Account/Login

**Must look above url difference .But it's gone same page**

But when i put this `http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase` url, *Why images are not shown ?*

And the same problem in  click this  *(pass query string )*:

> http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Discussion/ViewDiscussion/24

and then click this

> http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Discussion/ViewDiscussion?id=24

when i put `http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Discussion/ViewDiscussion/24` , Why Images are not shown ?

My Image path is

```
url('**../Images/sidecurve.png**')
```

But i have already tried `../../` and `~/` . But bad luck it's not working

Any one help me .

**Update** :

But When i put full url for

```
background: url('**http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/Images/sidecurve.png**') repeat-y;
```

This time working .

What problem ?

Comment: it seems that url image path is not set correctly,may you please mentioned that what's your image path..

Comment: ../Images/sidecurve.png .Please see one more in my question

Comment: Please can you share/show the code you have written? And possibly your folder structure. As it will be much easier to look at it, then to view the links and do Inspect element.

Comment: Please see my Update question . I can't understand this for what problem !

Comment: have you tried "Images/sidecurve.png" instead of "../Images/sidecurve.png"

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran in site http://epstechno.com/schoolbriefcase/ "Images/sidecurve.png" displays images using firebug

Comment: Thnks. finally i got it  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16186669/2291535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i am find it . I used @Url.Content it's worked

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logo1.jpg")" />
```